# How to disable caching in windows server 2012 R2?

Tags: cache, windows-server-2012-r2, memory-management

How to disable caching in windows server 2012 R2 ? Any way to set it to a minimal value is also fine. Also disabling caching for a particular application will also work as only 1 application is run continuously and doesn't use cache.Is there any equivalent of dynamic cache service for windows 2012 ? Can I use hyper V to achieve the same ?

Comment: I am running a in-memory application were the application actively rights in the RAM so there is no need for caching it only slows the down the process by caching 30 GB dataset which is already written to memory by the application as partitioned data sets.